# Can't connect Samsung Galaxy S3 to my laptop

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, connection-issues

My phone (Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.3) is charging but, will not connect to my laptop.

The data cable I used first charges my phone but I cannot see it on my laptop.

It also instantly stops connecting to my phone but it supports other phones.

How can I access my phone on my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

To access files from your phone on your computer, you need to have it hosted as a media device. Often these are found in your settings (in my case, when I plug the USB cable my phone asks me whether to charge phone only, or host as media device.) These are most likely found in your settings if it does not ask. Once you get that far, you need the drivers for your phone to be installed on the computer. Often they automatically install once your phone connects, but you may need to install them manually. Feel free to comment for anything you don't understand, but please try to make it understandable. They can be found here for your phone: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads